# Как избавиться от конфликта имен Excel при открытии через win32com?

Tags: python, excel

Всем привет.
Есть Excel 2016 (x64) и Python 2.7 (x64) с библиотекой win32com.
Нужно обработать много больших файлов в формате .XLSB (openpyxl не подходит).
Задача: забрать данные с одного из листов.
Итак, есть такой фрагмент кода

```
import win32com.client as wapi
excel_app = wapi.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel_app.Visible = False
excel_app.DisplayAlerts = False
excel_app.ScreenUpdating = False
wbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly=0)
```

И вот последняя строка вызывает такое окно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При открытии файла обычным путем, то есть через Эксель, это окно не появляется.
Как его можно отключить или обйти?

Должно наверно быть какое-то свойство `excel_app.SomeProperty = False`

Вот здесь бы разобраться: [Элементы ApplicationClass - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.applicationclass_members.aspx)

Вылетает еще и такая ошибка из-за разрядной несовместимости макроса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то заблокировать/отключить/удалить макросы во время открытия файла через Python + win32com? В самом Экселе можно заблокировать.

Answer (score 1):

Указанные сообщения, по всей видимости, создаются именно макросом, который запускается при открытии Excel-файла.

Макросы срабатывают по событиям, поэтому перед открытием документа нужно заблокировать события `Application.EnableEvents = False`. Тогда Ваш пример кода станет таким:

```
import win32com.client as wapi
excel_app = wapi.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel_app.Visible = False
excel_app.DisplayAlerts = False
excel_app.ScreenUpdating = False
excel_app.Application.EnableEvents = False
wbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly=0)
```

Тестировал на Windows 7 x64, Python 3.6.1, Excel 2007. Для теста использовал  Excel-файл с таким макросом:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

MsgBox "Welcome to ANALYSIS TABS"

End Sub
```